# How to set a default selected option in Android popup menu?

Tags: android, android-layout

I am using following code to create a menu:

```
    PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(getApplicationContext(), v);
    MenuInflater inflater = popup.getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.equalizer, popup.getMenu());
    popup.show();
```

equalizer.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <group android:checkableBehavior="single">
        <item android:id="@+id/flat"
              android:title="Flat" />
        <item android:id="@+id/stadium"
              android:title="Stadium" />
        <item android:id="@+id/jazz"
              android:title="Jazz" />
         <item android:id="@+id/rock"
              android:title="Rock" />
         <item android:id="@+id/pop"
              android:title="Pop" />
    </group>
</menu>
```

How is it possible to set, let's say, 3rd option of the menu as selected by default?

---

**EDIT:**
I would like to change defaults programmatically.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Answers have been given for setting a checked item in xml. If you want to do it in code, use:

```
popup.getMenu().getItem(2).setChecked(true);
```

to select the 3rd item. **After** you inflated the menu of course...

Comment: As I said, I would like to set not a specific element, but ordered.. like 1st or 5th or 2nd.

Comment: Ok, edited the response. Use `getItem()` instead of `findItem()`

Comment: In case you are also adding the menu items programmatically, you would need to set `popup.getMenu().setGroupCheckable(0, true, true)` before using `setChecked()`.

Answer (score 5):

```
<item android:id="@+id/jazz"
  android:title="Jazz"
  android:checked="true" />
```

Answer (score 2):

Set `android:checked="true"` in item which you want select default.

Comment: Sorry, I meant programmatically

Comment: I think ekholm answered your question.